# Consolidate 2 kusto queries (Application Insights API for custom events)

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have two kusto queries (2 custom events) as follows:

```
customEvents
| where name == "JobsStarted"
| order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp,
          Id = tostring(customDimensions["Id"]),
          Frequency = toint(customDimensions["Frequency"]),
          JobsStarted = toint(customDimensions["JobsStarted"])
| summarize Percentage = (toreal(countif(JobsStarted >= 1)) / sum(Frequency)) * 100
```

which outputs first Percentage value (let's say 100)

```
customEvents
| where name == "JobsCompleted"
| order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp,
          Id = tostring(customDimensions["Id"]),
          Frequency = toint(customDimensions["Frequency"]),
          JobsCompleted= toint(customDimensions["JobsCompleted"])
| summarize Percentage = (toreal(countif(JobsCompleted >= 1)) / sum(Frequency)) * 100
```

which outputs second Percentage value (let's say 97)

Is there a way to consolidate these two kusto queries and return a single Percentage value For example -> (100 + 97)/2 = 98.5

Comment: you may want to clarify what you mean by *"consolidate"* - e.g. if percentage of jobs started is X%, and percentage of jobs completed is Y%, what is your desired *"single Percentage value"*, as a function of X & Y?

Answer (score 0):

here are two options:

1.

```
customEvents
| where name in("JobsCompleted","JobsStarted")
| extend Frequency = toint(customDimensions["Frequency"]),
          JobsCompleted = toint(customDimensions["JobsCompleted"]),
          JobsStarted = toint(customDimensions["JobsStarted"])
| summarize P1 = (toreal(countif(JobsStarted >= 1)) / sumif(Frequency, name  == "JobsStarted")) * 100,
            P2 = (toreal(countif(JobsCompleted >= 1)) / sumif(Frequency, name == "JobsCompleted")) * 100
| project (P1 + P2) / 2
```

2. 

```
let P1 = toscalar(
    customEvents
    | where name == "JobsStarted"
    | extend Frequency = toint(customDimensions["Frequency"]),,
             JobsStarted = toint(customDimensions["JobsStarted"])
    | summarize Percentage = (toreal(countif(JobsStarted >= 1)) / 
    sum(Frequency)) * 100
);
let P2 = toscalar(
    customEvents
    | where name == "JobsCompleted"
    | extend Frequency = toint(customDimensions["Frequency"]),
             JobsCompleted = toint(customDimensions["JobsCompleted"])
    | summarize Percentage = (toreal(countif(JobsCompleted >= 1)) / sum(Frequency)) * 100
);
print (P1 + P2) / 2
```